# Not able to inject resolved object from ui-route change into the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to access an http get response called during route change using ui route. The resolve itself happens but i am unable to access the response. I have tried some approaches in "listcontroller" which is shown. I am using a sample httpget url found in the internet for test. Angular version: v1.2.32. ui-route: 1.0.15.

script.js

```
var app = angular.module("Rasp", ["ui.router"])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider
        .state("ipList", {
            url: "/ipList",
            templateUrl: "templates/list.html",
            controller: "listController",
            resolve: {
                SensorIP : function($http){
                    $http.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log('res');
                        console.log(response);
                        return response.data.origin;
                    });
                }
            }
        })
        .state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
            controller: "homeController"
        });
}])

.controller("RaspController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getDetails = function () {
//            $http.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
//                .then(function (response) {
//                    console.log(response);
//                    $scope.response = response;
//                },
//                function (error) { console.log(error); }
//                );
//        };

}])

.controller("homeController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {


}])
.controller("listController", ['$scope','SensorIP',function ($scope,SensorIP) {
    $scope.sensorList = SensorIP;
    var vm = this;
    this.list1 = SensorIP;
    var logfunc = function() {console.log($scope.sensorlist)};

}])
```

list.html

```
<div>
 {{list1}}
 {{sensorlist}}
 <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" ng-click="logfunc()">click</button>
 </div>
```

home.html

```
<h4>Click on "Get IP List" to get the list of IPs</h4>
<a ui-sref="ipList"><button id="button" >Get IP List</button></a>
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Title(To be changed)</title>
    <!--JS-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- -->
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- -->
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="Rasp">
        <div ng-controller="RaspController">
            <div class="sidenav">
<!--
                <a ui-sref="home" id="dot-button"><button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" >Home</button></a>
                <a ui-sref="ipList" id="dot-button"><button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" >IP List</button></a>
-->
                <a ui-sref="home">home</a>
                <a ui-sref="ipList" >ipList</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ui-view id="uiview"></ui-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `return $http.get('https:....` the `return` is important

Comment: Thanks...can't believe i missed that.